# Java - threadsafe collection that sorts on remove/take

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, queue

I have a situation whereby I need a threadsafe queue that runs a sort every time the remove() method is called and only when that method is called. This is because the objects can dynamically change "priority" after they have been added to the collection due external factors. This also needs to be threadsafe. There is no point extending something like the PriorityBlockingQueue because it will run the comparison function when additions are made. I failed to find any such collection/queue, so I tried to implement my own by just wrapping around an array list:

```
public class BlockingSortOnTakeQueue<E> implements Queue<E>
{
    private ArrayList<E> m_list;

    public BlockingSortOnTakeArrayList()
    {
        m_list = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized E remove() 
    {
        m_list.sort(m_comparator);
        return m_list.remove(0);
    }

    ....
```

Unfortunately, I am having difficulty figuring out how to ensure that the object type `<E>` has to implement the compareable interface, and to use that objects compareTo function when trying to sort the list (in the code I have m_comparator which is unfinished/placeholder).

**Does anyone know a threadsafe queue that only sorts on remove() or how to fix the start of my custom collection so as to use the generic objects compareTo function to sort the list.**

Comment: You say something like "public class BlockingSortOnTakeQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're doing it the way it has to be done.  To force the `Comparable` interface, write

```
public class BlockingSortOnTakeQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Queue<E> {
  ...
  @Override
  public synchronized E remove() {
    Collections.sort(m_list);
    return m_list.remove(0);
  }
}
```

...though it might be to your advantage to sort in reverse order, with `Collections.sort(m_list, Collections.reverseOrder())`, and to remove the last element, since that's faster in an `ArrayList`.

It might also be better to just identify the minimum element, rather than sorting the entire list, which would be O(n) instead of O(n log n).

Comment: Good spot! I didn't think of the fact that I only need to pass through the collection once to find the min/max so a sort is not necessary/waste

Comment: In that case, use a LinkedList, not an ArrayList.

Comment: @Programster, a synchronized find-min is still a big potential bottleneck. Have you considered using a priority queue and letting it know every time a priority changes?

Comment: I was initially running a priorityqueue but did not know how to force a re-sort. Perhaps the best thing is to remove/add elements when they become "dirty"?

Comment: @Programster, yes, that is likely best if the queue is large relative to the update frequency. Many priority queue implementations support a fast decreaseKey operation that you should use when you can.

Comment: Even if there are loads of updates, there will be less risk of blocking for a long time with the priority queue approach. If the queue is minuscule, of course, that changes things.

Comment: You'll almost certainly have to roll your own priority queue, and you can only decrease the key, not increase the key, in most implementations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I don't know why the OP would need to roll their own, but needing to change priorities dynamically does complicate matters. Increasing a key is just a matter of marking the node with a new key and reinserting it when it reaches the top (I believe); decreasing a key seems more problematic in a concurrent setting, as it seems likely to rule out many/most/all lock-free approaches. I don't know much about this sort of thing though.

Answer (score 0):

> objects can dynamically change "priority" after they have been added to the collection due external factors. This also needs to be threadsafe.

So what will happen if those "external factors" change objects in the collection while the sort algorithm is running?  It could corrupt the list, and your example code does not show how you prevent it from happening.  Those "external factors" must synchronize on the same object as your remove() function if you want to avoid that problem.

Also, will it cause a problem for you if your code successfully removes the highest priority item, and then, before you can do whatever it is you were planning to do with it, an "external factor" runs, and causes some other object, still in the collection, to have an even higher priority?  If so, then instead of just synchronizing the remove() function, you will need to synchronize whatever block of code it is that calls remove(), *and* performs the operation.

Comment: You raise a very good point. Queue order corruption could occur in cases that extend my simplified example. For my specific case this is not a problem, but is too long winded to explain. In simple terms, it would be "acceptable" (wont cause errors) if the remove() returned any element in the collection, but is ideal if it returns the "best" element and worth spending the CPU time to try and find it. I will also use a search for the min element rather than a sort as Louis Wasserman suggested.